# Carousel stopped working when i implemented some more angular js code for the data coming from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Earlier, I had implemented carousel(silder) which was working fine.

my earlier code:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="jcarousel-wrapper" style="margin:5px auto;">
                 <div class="jcarousel ">
                    <ul class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f68200;padding-bottom: 0px;">
                       <li>
                          <div class="span3">
                             <a href="#"><img src="./images/homeSlider01.jpg" style="width: 225px;height: 220px;"/></a>
                             <p ng-repeat="label in carouselOfLocationLabels | filter:'Location6'" class="home-slider1" style="text-align:left;"> {{label.text}}</p>
                          </div>
                       </li>
                       .......
                       .......                  
                    </ul>
                 </div>
                 <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">prev</a>
                 <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">next</a>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
```

Then I have modified few lines in order to get images from the server response. that's it.

here, the current code is:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
           <div class="jcarousel-wrapper" style="margin:5px auto;">
                 <div class="jcarousel ">
                 <input type="hidden" id="slider1length" value="{{featuredListSlider1Length}}"/>
                    <ul class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f68200;padding-bottom: 0px;">
                       <li class="featuredListSlider1" ng-repeat="label in featuredListSlider1">
                          <div  class="span3">
                             <div id="featuredListSlider1{{$index}}" style="margin: -3.5%;">{{label.url}}</div>
                             <p class="home-slider1" style="text-align:left;"> {{label.title}}{{label.price}}</p>
                          </div>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
                 <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">prev</a>
                 <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">next</a>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

It's showing in the same format with server responded images well but it stopped sliding.

In console i find only a single error as : (when i click on the prev or next controls)

```
 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of null "
```

Don't know why it's stopped working.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: please provide a plunkr or jsfiddle, thx

Comment: There are complex lines of code as the server involvement is also there. so, creating a jsfiddle is a big stuff for me. I have edditted it please go through it once more, and it would be much appreciable if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess, based on the code of jCarousel (https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/blob/master/dist/jquery.jcarousel.js), is that it detects the `<input>` element inside your `<div class="jcarousel ">` and sees it as not containing a list. Is it possible to move it outside of the carousel div?

```
<div class="wrapper">
       <div class="jcarousel-wrapper" style="margin:5px auto;">
             <input type="hidden" id="slider1length" value="{{featuredListSlider1Length}}"/>
             <div class="jcarousel ">
                <ul class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f68200;padding-bottom: 0px;">
                   <li class="featuredListSlider1" ng-repeat="label in featuredListSlider1">
                      <div  class="span3">
                         <div id="featuredListSlider1{{$index}}" style="margin: -3.5%;">{{label.url}}</div>
                         <p class="home-slider1" style="text-align:left;"> {{label.title}}{{label.price}}</p>
                      </div>
                   </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">prev</a>
             <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">next</a>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```